# Problem with gulp iconfonts, what i missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Where is problem? https://i.ibb.co/L0PsxWV/Screenshot-5.png

I have install gulp 3.9.1, and NODE.js 10.13.3...

```
"use strict";

var iconfont = require('gulp-iconfont');
var runTimestamp = Math.round(Date.now()/1000);

gulp.task('Iconfont', function(){
  return gulp.src(['src/icons/*.svg'])
    .pipe(iconfont({
      fontName: 'myfont', // required
      prependUnicode: true, // recommended option
      formats: ['ttf', 'eot', 'woff'], // default, 'woff2' and 'svg' are available
      timestamp: runTimestamp, // recommended to get consistent builds when watching files
    }))
      .on('glyphs', function(glyphs, options) {
        // CSS templating, e.g.
        console.log(glyphs, options);
      })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/fonts/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this top of gulpfile.js :

var gulp = require('gulp')